# Webservice which gives the pictures for nearby places from current latitude-longitude in iphone

Tags: iphone

is there any webserivce which gives the pictures of the nearby location of the current latitude and longitude.I want to implement this in iphone .
I had tried to use Flickr and four square api.
four square and  Flickr the problem i m facing is it is giving too many junk data in response!!
Means 2 out of 10 was correct.
I want to use this webservice globally not for particular countries or location.
Please help me and reply me as soon as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i m not sure whether you can get pictures of places

But for implementing location specific search - i would recommend these API's

Facebook Checkins - https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=restaurant&type=place&center=lat,long&distance=1000

Foursquare API - https://developer.foursquare.com/

Google Places API - Refer their doc before using this -  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

Gowalla API - http://gowalla.com/api/docs

Of which - Foursquare gives more locations compare with Facebook & others

http://www.aleemmawani.com/2011/04/facebook-places-vs-foursquare-checkins.html

http://www.dmolsen.com/mobile-in-higher-ed/2011/06/16/more-numbers-foursquare-vs-facebook-places-vs-gowalla-at-wvu/

But for easy implementation - Others are too good than foursquare!
Hoe this Helps ,

Comment: @karthikeyan.Thanks for the reply.But This api's will not work.Google will give image of only icon and four square and facebook will give the images which people had uploaded i want the images of the nearby places like http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Delhi&prop=images&format=xml.As this is showing the list of the name of .jpg image not the url of that .jpg image.I want the url of that .jpg image so that i can put that image directly in device.

Comment: This question is still open if any one can had better idea can post it here!!

Comment: @shweta : Thanks &  i have used these all api's , i m pretty sure images for places are not available , i would be great for me if there is any option - Having currently working in loc.search app , But i find images in facebook places web page - havent find any image tag ,  Also if u run all these apps - Facebook , Four2 , Gowalla , Google-Places - they didnt show images for places,only symbolic icons? Anyway will update any if i come across!

Comment: i get the solution.You can use this api's for getting the images url:-http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=india&generator=images&gimlimit=10&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url|dimensions|mime.It will help u.If u have any doubt please post it here may be i can help u out

Comment: @Thanks & But shweta - does it allows passing location parameters?

Comment: @karthikeyan.Location parameter in what sense??means passing lat long??Can u please tell me what actually u want in response and what actually stuff u have to which can be  pass in the request

Comment: Thanks shweta - This is the flow , pass lat/lng - get places (Restraunts) - select Restraunt - Select items - Pay by Card. so i must a lat/lng to avail nearby places - which in turn i ll ping that place to app server to get available items to purchase !

Comment: I had done similar kind of thing in my project.I had used google Api for this instead of wikipedia.U can use this API:-"http://www.google.co.in/maps?q=Restaurants&sll=23.000,72.000&radius=100&output=json".In the place of restaurant u can give any place like Hospitals,hotels,Shopping malls Etc.Try this it will really work.If u want it in detail in coding Please post the question in ur account.So that i can give u proper answer and also get some reputations :)

Comment: @Shweta : I m already done with Foursquare & completed Now , & Only thing i m looking for Images for Places ,

Comment: @Karthikeyan.Ok then u can do it http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=india&generator=images&gimlimit=10&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url|dimensions|mime. u have to pass the location name only.Can't pass latlong or restuarants like that.U have to only pass the name with proper spelling given in wikipediya